# Don't understand java operator ? and :

Tags: java

```
public static void openWebpage(URI uri) {
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;
    if (desktop != null && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
        try {
            desktop.browse(uri);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And I don't know what the ? and the : at the end is meaning.

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;
```

is equivalent to

```
Desktop desktop;
if( Desktop.isDesktopSupported() )
    desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
else
    desktop = null;
```

Ternary operators is what this is called. `<condition> ? <true part> : <false part>`

Comment: Ok Thanks but its duplicated i dont know that i could not find it. Sorry I'll delete it.

Comment: it's fine, i guess

Comment: It's hard to Google it when you don't know what it's called. Confuses lots if people.

Comment: @Merduma It would be nice, if you could accept/upvote an answer if your issue is resolved. From [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), "Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved."

Comment: I couldn't check it because you can't check it in the first minutest.

Comment: @Merduma Yep! I understand. Glad I could help. :)